# Why does this HTML never trigger this jQuery function?

Tags: jquery

I did not define `showprayer` as a class in my CSS stylesheet.

Is that the reason this jQuery function is never called for the HTML below?

```
    $('.showprayer').click( function(event) 
    {
      console.log("showprayer");

      $.post('/show_prayer', { 'name' : $(this).text() }, function(data) 
      {
           //... do something with the data returned from the post
      });
    });


    <a href="#" id="showprayer_106" class="showprayer">
        <tr id="prayer_106" >
            <td>Prayer <span class="prayerspn" id="prayerspn_106">106</span></td>
            <td>03/19/1968</td>
        </tr>
    </a>
```

I'm trying to pass the `prayerId` (in this case `106` to the `/show_prayer` handler. There's probably a simpler way to do it but the easiest way I can think of is to put it inside the span above:

```
<span class="prayerspn" id="prayerspn_106">106</span></td>
```

And then pull the text (`"106"`) out of the span and pass it in the `$.post` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTML is invalid. `<tr>` elements may not be children of `<a>` elements. Whatever your browser is doing to try to recover from the error probably ends up with the `<a>` element being empty and thus not having any clickable pixels.

Always [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your markup.

The URI "show_prayer" strongly suggests that this function is all about getting and displaying information. If it is, then a link is the right choice (but you should change the JS so it makes a GET request instead of a POST request), otherwise you should be looking at using a form instead.

Assuming that a link is the right way forward then [it should point to something more sensible](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build) than the top of the page.

If we apply the above to the code, then we get something like:

```
<tr id="prayer_106" >
    <td><a href="/show_prayer?name=106">Prayer 106</a></td>
    <td>03/19/1968</td>
</tr>
```

You can then apply JS along the lines of:

```
function handlePrayer(e) {
    var uri = jQuery('a', this).attr('href');
    jQuery.get(uri, function (data) { /* Do something with the returned data */ };
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
}
jQuery('table.myTable tr').click(handlePrayer);
```

jQuery will add an HTTP header (X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest) that you can use to decide if /show_prayer should return a complete HTML document or just the data you want to process with JavaScript.

Comment: I would change pixels to elements but otherwise that's probably the case :)

Comment: There might be an element left in the DOM, but sized in such a way that it is impossible to click on, which is why I used the term pixels there.